# Mocking Webexception including Webresponse

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

I am trying to write a Unit test where a dependency of my *sut* (authMock) should throw a Webexception with a specific response (json which will be parsed in the sut accordingly). However I have trouble throwing the Webexception using Moq like that:

```
 Stream responseStream = null;
 using (var stringstream = @"{""errocode"": ""35""}".ToStream())
 {
    responseStream = stringstream;
 }
 var webresponse = new Mock<WebResponse>();
 webresponse.Setup(c => c.GetResponseStream()).Returns(responseStream);

 authMock.Setup((x) => x.UserAuthentification(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).
          Throws(new WebException("fu", null,WebExceptionStatus. TrustFailure, webresponse.Object));

 sut.GetUserAuthentification(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), (s) => response = s);

//Asserts here
```

The Webexception is being thrown but when I try to catch it in my sut and try to read the stream an ArgumentException is being thrown:

```
    ex.Response.GetResponseStream   error CS0103: The name 'ex' does not exist in the current context
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what i've done for same question

```
private void StubCallerToThrowNotFoundException(string iprange)
    {
        var response = new Mock<HttpWebResponse>();
        response.Setup(c => c.StatusCode).Returns(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        mocker.Setup<ICaller>(x => x.GetResponseAsync(It.Is<string>(p => !p.Contains(iprange))))
            .Throws(new WebException("Some test exception", null, WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError, response.Object));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So apparently the problem had nothing to do with the exception itself or the way I am trying to mock it but with my lack of understanding Streams in C# (and I am still not sure what the exact problem is).
When I do not use the using statement when converting the string into a stream everything works fine. For clarification here is my extension method I was using in the example top:

```
 public static Stream ToStream(this string str)
{
    var expectedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
    var responseStream = new MemoryStream();
    responseStream.Write(expectedBytes, 0, expectedBytes.Length);
    responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return responseStream;
}
```

so I guess I will refresh my knowledge about streams.